# How to install ROS on BeagleBoard Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ros, installation, beagleboard, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any useful info please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9166/how-to-install-ros-on-beagleboard-ubuntu-10.10?/) by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2011-02-22

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd rather install Diamondback than CTurtle. You definitely have to use SVN-install. Also, as I already pointed out in [your earlier post](http://answers.ros.org/question/127/how-much-space-is-required-for-a-complete-install#205), read [REP108](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0108.html). Then just do as it says on the [Wiki Diamondback SVN installation page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/SVN), possibly replacing variant with one of those more suitable for your needs as described in the aforementioned [REP108](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0108.html).

**EDIT (see Koen's posts in this thread !!):** An other possibility is using installation scripts provided by Koen Buys on his [page](http://people.mech.kuleuven.be/%7Eu0062536/embsensor.html).

You can also read my [previous posts](http://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/), they, for now, mainly regard the issue of your interest.

Cheers, Tom

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to successfully install ROS on an IGEPv2 board, which is very similar to the original Beagleboard. Here's a rough list of steps:

1. You'll have to get a working Ubuntu
   10.10 install on the Beagleboard.
2. Next, do an SVN-based install. You
   can find directions for Cturtle at
   [Installing on Ubuntu from
   SVN](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Ubuntu/SVN).
   This will take some time to install,
   as it will have to build a lot from
   source on the Beagleboard. You may
   also have to skip installing certain
   packages that include GUI things.
   For example, I don't remember if
   Ogre compiled successfully on my
   IGEPv2 board - if it didn't, then
   anything that depends on Ogre such
   as rviz would fail to compile.
   However, since I intended the board
   to be a headless computer, I didn't
   really care much if visualization
   tools failed to compile and install.

If you prefer to cross-compile, checkout the docs for [eros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros), which is a set of packages and tools for cross-compiling and install ROS on embedded systems.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-02-22**:
I'd rather install Diamondback, see my post.

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-02-22**:
I'll try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We did the same on Beagleboard and Beagleboard XM, however we didn't install any X-server related things because we only use it to interface robots (Pioneer + Peoplebot) or sensors (Hokuyo, Sick, ...) to the network. I had an old SD card image on my website, I'll take the time to put a new one online, if people show interest for it.
We'll soon be putting a crosscompile toolchain tutorial online for the Beagleboard (after it got tested with students in a course).

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an old question but has a lot of views. Thought I'd post my tutorial here. ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.10 on BeagleBoard-xM:

http://sysadminfixes.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/ros-on-beaglebuntu/

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1